# I am creating a PL SQL function in oracle 19c to find largest among two numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have created the function named findLargest as show below :
And I am trying to call it ,but i am getting errors as show below :

```
SQL> CREATE FUNCTION findLargest (x IN NUMBER, y IN NUMBER)
  2  RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS z NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5  IF x > y THEN
  6     z:= x;
  7  ELSE
  8     z:=y;
  9  END IF;
 10  RETURN z;
 11  END;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Can you plz tell whats wrong with the calling block??

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  a:= 10;
  3  b := 20;
  4  c := 0;
  5  BEGIN
  6  c := findLargest(a,b);
  7  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| c);
  8  END;
  9  /
a:= 10;
 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
constant exception <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
character nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
constant exception <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
character nchar
```

I am posting question on stackoverflow for 1st time.So plz bare with me if you find something weird!

Comment: What's wrong with simply using `greatest()`?

Comment: In the *DECLARE* section, when you declare a variable, you must also state its **data type** - whether you assign a value to it or not. Even thought `a := 10` should suggest to the parser that you mean `a` as `number` data type, the language doesn't allow that; you must declare as `a number := 10`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It seems pretty clear to me (although perhaps not to you) that the OP is practicing writing functions, as part of the learning process. If that is the case, then "what's wrong with simply using `greatest()`" becomes obvious.

Comment: It's her homework. @mathguy has a point.

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot the datatype after the variable name:

```
a INTEGER := 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have not declared the data types of the variables:

```sql
DECLARE
  a NUMBER := 10;
  b NUMBER := 20;
  c NUMBER;
BEGIN
  c := findLargest(a,b);
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| c);
END;
/
```

*(You also do not need to assign a value to the `c` variable.)*

You can write the calling block in a simpler manner by eliminating the intermediate variables:

```sql
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| findLargest(10,20));
END;
/
```

However, there is a problem with your function if you pass a `NULL` value:

```sql
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| findLargest(10,NULL));
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| findLargest(NULL,10));
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Largest number is : 
> Largest number is : 10
> ```

The issue is that both `10 > NULL` and `NULL > 10` do not return truthy values so in both cases the `y` value is returned rather than returning a `NULL` value.

You can fix this by checking for `NULL` values (and using a `CASE` statement and no intermediate variables):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION findLargest (x IN NUMBER, y IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN CASE
         WHEN x IS NULL OR y IS NULL
         THEN NULL
         WHEN x > y
         THEN x
         ELSE y
         END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| findLargest(10,20));
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| findLargest(10,NULL));
  dbms_output.put_line ('Largest number is : '|| findLargest(NULL,10));
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Largest number is : 20
> Largest number is : 
> Largest number is :
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97a73ca5cc8212a5b484a3fea818e3f8)*

Answer (score 1):

Just for amusement, so that you wouldn't have to pick greatest of only two numbers, you could pass a collection to the function, sort values in descending order and pick the first one. Something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_great (par_list in sys.odcinumberlist)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select cv
  7      into retval
  8      from (select column_value cv,
  9              row_number() over (order by column_value desc) rn
 10            from table(par_list)
 11           )
 12      where rn = 1;
 13    return retval;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_great(sys.odcinumberlist(1, 5, 23, 18, -2)) result_1,
  2         f_great(sys.odcinumberlist(-100, -2.1, -2.2)) result_2
  3  from dual;

  RESULT_1   RESULT_2
---------- ----------
        23       -2,1

SQL>
```